# undefined method 'find_by_email' Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Okay I have been working on this for about 2 hours and am sure there is a very simple solution but unfortunately as a rails novice I can't seem to find it.

I have set up a basic sign up and login system following Ryan Bates Authetication lesson #270.

I keep however receiving the same error when trying to login.

```
undefined method `find_by_email' for nil:NilClass
```

I have my sessions controller set up as follows:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    def new
    end

    def create
        user = user.find_by_email(params[:email])
        if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
            session[:user_id] = user.id
            redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged in!"
        else
            flash.now.alert = "Invalid email or password"
            render "new"
        end
    end

    def destroy
        session[:user_id] = nil
        redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged Out!"
    end

end
```

But am really unsure how to define find_by_email.

Any advice people can offer me on this really would be much appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
user.find_by_email(params[:email])
```

should be

```
User.find_by_email(params[:email])
```

Comment: This is one of those crazy things where `user` would be undefined and throw an error but for the fact that it's defined in the assignment, the classic `a = a` situation.

Comment: Lucapette - thanks so much for this it worked instantly and was exactly what I needed! :)

Comment: @TomPinchen glad it worked! Please accept the answer if it solved tour problem. Will help for the next questions ;)